# Using _T on a std::string

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I'm trying to use this line of code

```
startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\" +  caseref);
```

But as  I understand, I'm not allowed to use _T on a variable.
Basically I'm trying to set the starting folder of the SHBrowseForFolder as a path made up of variables assigned earlier on.
I've spent ages trying to get around it, been searching and found stuff about wstrings but nothing seems to work. I hope it's something easy that I've missed because I can't believe it's this difficult to _T a variable.

```
void folderdialog2()
                 {    
                     PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE xx;
                     PCTSTR startingfolder; 

                     startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\" +  caseref);
                     xx = ILCreateFromPath(startingfolder);

                     BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
                     bi.pidlRoot = xx;
                     bi.lpszTitle = _T("Pick a Directory");

                     LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder ( &bi );
                     if ( pidl != 0 )
                     {
                         // get the name of the folder
                         TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
                         if ( SHGetPathFromIDList ( pidl, path ) )
                         {
                             _tprintf ( _T("Selected Folder: %s\n"), path );                                                                           
                         }
                         // free memory used
                         IMalloc * imalloc = 0;
                         if ( SUCCEEDED( SHGetMalloc ( &imalloc )) )
                         {
                             imalloc->Free ( pidl );
                             imalloc->Release ( );
                         }                               
                     }           

                 }
```

Comment: it's the name of a folder taken from user input at the start of the program

Comment: I mean, how do you declare that variable? What is its type?

Comment: sorry it's a std::string

Comment: As far as I remember Microsoft stuff, _T only works with string literals (that is, constants). It works by prefixing the string literal with L if you are in widestring mode (as in `L"..."`) so obviously it can't transform a std::string into std::wstring.

Comment: @syam, That's exactly it. It's just a macro that conditionally adds an L.

Comment: @syam, is there a way around that do you know?
I can't believe no one has ever had a need to string literal something in a variable

Comment: @Mike: it's been a long time I had to deal with such things (why won't MS just use UTF8 everywhere like any sane OS?), as a wild guess I'd say you should use either std::string or std::wstring based on some `#ifdef` (but I don't remember the macro name that controls ANSI/Wide literals). Yes, that'll be ugly.

Comment: Stop using TCHAR,LPTSTR, and _T. These types and macros only useful if you are trying build for non-unicode aware platforms like Windows 98 and earlier. Unfortunately, lots of Microsoft APIs dcoumentation are still littered with TCHAR references. And it's still a mystery why the auto-generated source code for a new VS project includes tchar.h.  In any case, walk away from it, and use L"string" if you need a wchar string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
PCTSTR startingfolder;
startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\" +  caseref);
```

do this:

```
wstring const startingfolder = wstring() + L"C:\\VSS\\" + caseref;
```

and change your string types to wide strings, etc., and make sure that `UNICODE` is defined before including `<windows.h>`.

The Windows API is built on UTF-16 string representation, using a 16-bit `wchar_t`. When you use an ANSI function it has to translate to and from the wide character underlying API. So using ANSI strings is

- Inefficient.
- Limited (not able to handle general Unicode characters).
- A lot of extra work, and still most probably bugs left.

You need to support ANSI if you are using pretty old tools that still can target Windows 9x, and you mean to target Windows  9x, and you can't use Layer for Unicode because you're using MFC in DLLs and you don't feel that you're up to rebuilding that. But are you really targeting Windows 9x with MFC in DLL and using sufficiently old tools that you can do that? I doubt it!

So, use wide strings, everywhere.

---

Summing up, forget about the silly `_T` macros.

Comment: Cheers bud. That worked. Had to keep my `caseref` as a string, but made a new one called `widecaseref`. What a pain in the bum! Have a pretend beer on me!

Answer (score 3):

You may do this:

```
startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\") +  caseref;
```

But if `caseref` is declared as `std::string`, this won't compile when you're using the Unicode charset. On the other hand, if you declared it as `std::wstring`, it would not compile when you are using the multibyte charset.

If you need your program to support both character sets, one possible approach is to use a preprocessor directive to define a type alias `tstring` that resolves into `std::wstring` if the `_UNICODE` symbol is defined, and into `std::string` if not, and declare your string variables as `tstring`.

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef std::wstring tstring;
#else
typedef std::string tstring;
#endif

tstring casref = _T("something");
tstring startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\") + caseref;
```

Notice, however, that non-prehistoric (that is, any NT-based) versions of Windows work with Unicode characters internally, so if you have no particular reasons for supporting both configurations, just drop those ugly macros (including `_T`) and use the `L` prefix for string literals (e.g. `L"Hello"`) in combination with `std::wstring` (and wide versions of streams as well, if you are using them).

Comment: I think we should mention that "non-prehistoric" actually means any NT-based Windows (NT4, W2k, XP, etc). Also, +1 for explaining accurately what I said very loosely in my comment. ;)

Comment: @syam: Mentioned it, plus your comment will serve as additional info. Thank you :)

Comment: Had a  look at my project settings and it's set to unicode, so I converted casref to a wstring ( I think) using 

  `   std::wstring widecaseref;`
              widecaseref.assign(caseref.begin(), caseref.end());`

then I used 

     startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\") + widecaseref;

but I get

Error 1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'PCTSTR'


Am I way off?

P.S. sorry I haven't got the hang of putting code in these comment boxes

Comment: Oh man, this is hurting my head

`caseref` gets set from the value of a text box on a different form. also, `startingfolder` needs to be a `PCTSTR`, so we can't set that as a `tstring` can we?

Comment: @Mike: `startingfolder` *should* be a `tstring`, or a `wstring`, if you are using only unicode. `std::string` and `std::wstring` have a member function called `c_str()` which returns a `char const*` or `wchar_t const*` (respectively). Now `PCTSTR` is nothing else than `char const*` (when multibyte charset is selected) and `wchar_t const*` (when Unicode charset is selected)

Comment: Right I see, all these different names for the same thing confusing me

I've changed `startingfolder` to a `wstring` and for the time being got rid of the reference to `caseref` 

`startingfolder = _T("C:\\VSS\\");`
and on this line `xx = ILCreateFromPath(startingfolder);`it says
`Error 1 error C2664: 'ILCreateFromPathW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'LPCWSTR'`

Comment: @Mike, By the way, you don't have to use `assign`. There's a constructor that takes two iterators. There's also `std::wstring_convert`. To get from a `basic_string` to a C string, use `c_str()`, as already mentioned.

Comment: 3 main problems. the first, pretending that there is any point in supporting Windows 9x with MFC in DLLs (we can be pretty sure the OP doesn't have a lot of legacy code to be concerned about, or he would not be stuck on this trivia problem). secondly, defining a macro instead of using a `typedef`. third, using a lowercase name for that macro.

Comment: @Alf (typing from mobile, please forgive the abbreviation): That's right, I should have been more careful. I edited my answer, thank you.

Comment: @AndyProwl: you're welcome. he he you forgot some semicolons. hope you're not driving! :-)

Comment: @Alf: Lol :) No, I just switched off the computer and called it a night. And I guess I should get some sleep, considering the mistakes. Thanks again, fixed