# pass a string to function that uses _T

Tags: c++

When trying to pass a `std::string` to `_T` I get this error

```
cpp_client.cpp: In function 'void GET(const char*, int, std::__cxx11::string, const char*)':
cpp_client.cpp:174:33: error: initializer fails to determine size of 'frmdata'
     static TCHAR frmdata[] = _T(data);
                                 ^
cpp_client.cpp:174:33: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I tried to add a parameter to the function that is the length of `std::string` but this does seem to solve the problem, I also found a question with the number `246806` over at stackoverflow that talks about how to do this and tried two examples which are commented inside the function but this also does not seem to help or fix the issue

I don't want to use `_T()` function outside of `GET` function since the `std::string` keeps on changing and I don't want to hardcode it in the code as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455969/using-t-on-a-stdstring) question

```
void GET(const char * host, int port,  std::string data , const char* endpoint ) 
{
    /*
    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(data.begin(), data.end());
    const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();

    std::wstring name( data );
    const wchar_t* szName = name.c_str();
    
    246806 <- number of stackoverflow question from where above code is taken 
    */
    static TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    static TCHAR frmdata[] = _T(data);
    static LPCSTR accept[2]={"*/*", NULL};

    // for clarity, error-checking has been removed
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("c++_agent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T(host), port, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "GET", _T(endpoint), NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
    // close any valid internet-handles
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string data = "{\"cmdline\": \" some value \" }";
    GET("192.168.1.7",5000, data ,"hello");

    return 0;
}
```

ditching `_T` creates a new problem

```
cpp_client.cpp: In function 'void GET(const char*, int, std::__cxx11::string, const char*)':
cpp_client.cpp:187:61: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'PVOID {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]
     HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), data.c_str() , data.length());
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from cpp_client.cpp:4:0:
c:\mingw\include\wininet.h:828:13: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'BOOL HttpSendRequestA(HINTERNET, LPCSTR, DWORD, PVOID, DWORD)'
 BOOL WINAPI HttpSendRequestA(HINTERNET,LPCSTR,DWORD,PVOID,DWORD);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

ps I am compiling with gcc on a windows 10

Comment: It's not possible to copy a string to a array allocated on the stack like this, since there's no way for the compiler to know what size to use for the `frmdata` array at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

What `_T` does is to conditionally add an `L` in front of the  string, depending on whether you are using "Unicode" or not. (This was once kind of useful for compiling the same source for both Windows 95 and Windows NT).

So `_T("Hello")` becomes `L"Hello"`, which is an array of `wchar_t`. That's all.

And `_T(data)` becomes `Ldata`, which doesn't make much sense to the compiler.

The solution is to decide whether you want `char`-strings or `wchar_t`-strings, and skip the `_T()` part.

Comment: yeah but this does not solve my question

Comment: @ahmad - The solution *is* to skip the `_T`-stuff, including `TCHAR`. It is just ancient and useless. As is, `data.c_str()` returns a `const char*` and `data.size()` gives its length. If you actually want to use `wchar_t`, just make `data` a `wstring` instead.

Comment: this creates a new problem @ ```HttpSendRequest```

Comment: @ahmad simply `const_cast` away the `const`, eg: `HttpSendRequestA(..., const_cast<char*>(data.c_str()), ...);` This is safe in this case as the parameter is treated as read-only data. It *should* have been declared as `const`, but that is not the way Microsoft declared it.